# Symfony 4 Error 500 after submit upload FileType Form

Tags: php, symfony4

This project gets an error 500 when I upload a file to a FileType Form in Symfony, however I have no clue where the issue is.
The controller and twig both seem fine, additionally the form behaved as expected shortly before an ENV devops issue, therefore I'm not even sure it's an issue with the code.

**Facts**

1. The project is set in DEV in the settings, however the server run command launches it in PROD (no debug bar)
2. The upload has worked prior to a server env change
3. The error 500 doesn't point me in any direction

**The Controller**

````
    {
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $verifyForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\VerifyType');
        $verifyForm->handleRequest($request);

        $uploadForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UploadType'); //this is the bugged form
        $uploadForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->get('session')->set('search', $form->getData());
            return $this->redirectToRoute('results');
        }

        $series = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:BacCandidatSerie')
            ->findAll();

        if ($verifyForm->isSubmitted() && $verifyForm->isValid()) {

            $ine = $verifyForm->getData(); 
            $ineValidator = new CodeValidator($ine['numero_ine']);
            if($ineValidator->testINE()){
                return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
                    'valid' => true,
                    'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
                    'series' => $series,
                    'isTested' => true,
                    'isInvalid' => false
                ));
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
                    'valid' => false,
                    'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
                    'series' => $series,
                    'isTested' => true,
                    'isInvalid' => true,
                ));
            }
        }

        if ($uploadForm->isSubmitted() && $uploadForm->isValid()) {
            $file = $uploadForm['fichier_ine']->getData(); //this worked previously but now seems not to
            dump($file);
            die();
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
            'valid' => false,
            'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
            'series' => $series,
            'isTested' => false,
            'isInvalid' => false
        ));
    }```

**The UploadFile Form**
```class UploadType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fichier_ine', FileType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('sendfile', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Vérifier les numéros'])
        ;
    }
}```

I'm looking for leads having spent 2 hours without any progress and being a junior beginner developer.
````

Comment: That's why every Symfony application gathers logs. You can find them inside the `var/log` directory. Without any log details we cannot help you.

Comment: The logs surprisingly stop 3 days ago, whereas I had the issue since yesterday evening. Therefore I am looking into this issue now and will upload the logs when I can get them, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**
Following @emix advices, I checked the log and found:

`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "dump" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller"." at /var/www/html/sisine/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 81`

The the following line in the controller made it break:

`dump($file)`

Somehow, the dump broke and I'm now using var_dump from native PHP and I'm able to resume my work.
Thank you